# Histogram scale error when using DistributionChart

Tags: plotting, histograms, charts

I'm a novice Mathematica user that is having some problems using the HistogramDensity function in a DistributionChart. My observations are heavily skewed to one category and the height of the other categories are larger than the number of observations should imply. Any ideas? Here's a stylized example of my problem:

```
data = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4}
DistributionChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementDataFunction["HistogramDensity", "Bins" -> 4]]
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you need to have a list of datasets, something like `Gather[data]` ?

Comment: I don't think its necessary with several datasets. It plots the histogram with no problem, its just the scales that are off...

Comment: In which way is `Histogram` not doing what you need to achieve ?

Comment: Below is the resulting histogram

Comment: Above I have included the resulting histogramdensity. As you can see the top category is almost as large as the two next even though it contains only one observation versus three and five in the other ...

Comment: It seems as though there's a "minimum" bar size for HistogramDensity, which definitely distorts the distribution.  Unfortunately, I can't offer a suggestion for eliminating the problem (other than to choose a different approach to plotting the distribution, such as SmoothDensity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidSkulsky commented the problem is due to the scaling inside `ChartElementDataFunction["HistogramDensity"]`.

A workaround is to use a custom `ChartElementDataFunction`. For example, the following transforms the `Rectangle`s produced by standard `Histogram` to produce "double-sided" and rotated rectangles:

```
ceF := Dynamic@(Histogram[#2, 4, "Probability", BarOrigin -> Left, 
   ChartStyle -> CurrentValue["Color"]][[1]] /. 
     RectangleBox[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}, z___] :> 
       RectangleBox[{-x1 + 2 #[[1, 1]], y0}, {x1 + 2 #[[1, 1]], y1}, z]) &
```

Using OP's `data`:

```
data = Join[ConstantArray[1, 50], {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4}];

DistributionChart[{data[[40 ;;]], Join[{0, 0, 0}, data[[30 ;;]]], data}, 
      ChartStyle -> "SandyTerrain", 
      ChartElementFunction -> ceF]
```

[image]