# Automatically sizing elements in a DistributionChart with custom ChartElementFunction

Tags: graphics, histograms, plotting

This is a follow-up to some related questions: [46770](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46770/histogram-scale-error-when-using-distributionchart) and [60600](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60600/weird-output-of-distributionchart).

---

I'd like to make a `DistributionChart` where the elements are histograms with my own custom settings. For example, I'd like to be able to take:

```
data = WeightedData[Range[10], #] & /@ RandomInteger[20, {5, 10}];
```

and make a `DistributionChart` where each element looks like, say,

```
Histogram[data[[i]],10,{"Log","Probability"}][[1]]
```

for the appropriate value of the iterator, `i` (ideally with the histogram bars centered rather than edge-aligned). I tried something similar to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46815):

```
Module[
  {cef :=
    Histogram[#2,10,{"Log", "Probability"}, BarOrigin -> Left][[1]] /. 
      RectangleBox[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}, z___] :> 
        RectangleBox[
          {(- x1  + #[[1, 1]] + #[[1,2]])/2, y0},
          {(x1 + #[[1, 1]] + #[[1, 2]])/2, y1}, z] &},
  DistributionChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> cef]]
```

The code above almost works, but because the bars of the histograms can have length greater than 1, they can overlap. (It works fine if `{"Log", "Probability"}` is changed to `"Probability"`.) I can fix this on a case-by-case basis by scaling down the bar lengths by some factor, but is there a way to do it automatically?